# Nodejs CompanyId is not appearing in console log

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphiql

I was just working on relating companies with users. I creates a new company field on the user type and I told it that it would be of type `CompanyType`.

My next step was to define a resolve function on this property so GraphQL knows how to find the company that is associated with a given user.

So my goal here is to take a user and find their associated company. I want to teach GraphQL how to walk from a user over to a company.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const axios = require('axios');
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLInt, GraphQLSchema } = graphql;

const CompanyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Company',
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    description: { type: GraphQLString }
  }
});

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    firstName: { type: GraphQLString },
    age: { type: GraphQLInt },
    company: {
      type: CompanyType,
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        console.log(parentValue, args);
      }
    }
  }
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLString } },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return axios
          .get(`http://localhost:3000/users/${args.id}`)
          .then(res => res.data);
      }
    }
  }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery
});
```

My expectation with `console.log(parentValue, args);` was to get this output in the console:

```
`{ id: '23', firstName: 'Bill', age: 20, companyID: '1' } {}`
```

after I went to graphiQL and hit the play button requesting this:

```
{
    user(id: "23") {
    firstName
    company {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Instead the output I got in console was this:

```
{ id: '23', firstName: 'Bill', age: 20 } {}
```

I am not sure why I have been unsuccessful in teaching GraphQL on how to get this data to populate this company property with the resolve function. Please help.

Comment: where are you getting the data from?

Comment: @Daniel, from my `db.json` file.

Comment: Can you post your `db.json` file please.